# AIRFLOW Redshift Hook

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

Airflow novice here

**Setup**

- env: MWAA
- db: Redshift

**Question:**
I am trying to write a task to loop through a list, use the list value in SQL and lastly use an if statement to determine appropriate action based on the results. Something like this but struggling a bit. If it is possible what's the best way to achieve it?

```
def duplicate_check():
    ls = ['table1','table2','table3','table4']
    
    for tables in ls:
        number_of_records = RedshiftSQLOperator(
                                        """
                                            SQL which returns me one record with a int output. Number of order ID duplicates. I'd like to use pass {{tables}} though?
                                        """
                                            )
        if number_of_records > 0:
            send_email = EmailOperator(
                ''
            )
        else:
            None
```

start >>  PythonOperator call above function >> end

Comment: This is not going to work. From your code it seems that you expect coding in Airflow to be like you code a Python script. it's not the same. Operators push values to xcom. you will need to pull the value in downstream task.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are trying to do similar thing at their end, this is how I was able to do it on my end.

**NOTE**: I'm using http request to send notifications to slack channel

````
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator 
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.decorators import dag
import requests
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


    def table_duplication_call(tbl_name,sql):
        # print('Start of function', context)
        slack_token = BaseHook.get_connection('slack_default').password
        url = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
    #     print(url)
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {slack_token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        
        data = {'channel': '#your_channel_name', 
                'mrkdwn':True,
                'text': f""":red_circle: Duplicates in {tbl_name} Table.
                        ```{sql}```
                    """}
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        return response.json()
        response.raise_for_status()
        print(response.json())
    

    default_args = {'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 2),
                    'retries': 1,
                    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20),
                    'email_on_failure': False}

    with DAG(
        dag_id="load_dag", 
        start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 2), 
        schedule_interval="15 */4 * * *", 
        tags=['some_tag'],
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup = False,
        description='Some description',
        default_view='graph', #grid, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
        on_failure_callback=None,
        on_success_callback=None,
        # on_failure_callback=send_email
        ) as dag:
    

        start = DummyOperator(
            task_id = 'start',
            dag=dag,
        )
        
        end = DummyOperator(
            task_id = 'end',
            dag=dag
        )
   

    tbl_ls = ['table1','table2','table3']


    def duplication_check_func():
            hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='redshift_default')
            for tbl in tbl_ls:
                sql = f"""
                                        select
                                                {tbl}.{tbl}_id duplicated_id,
                                                count({tbl}.{tbl}_id ) as cnt
                                            from
                                                datawarehouse.{tbl} 
                                            group by
                                                {tbl}_id 
                                            having
                                                cnt > 1;
                                        """
                results = hook.get_records(sql)
                if len(results)>0:
                    table_duplication_call(tbl_name={tbl},sql=sql)
                else:
                    None
            # return results
            

    db_duplication_notification = PythonOperator(
    task_id='db_duplication_notification',
    python_callable=duplication_check_func,
    dag=dag
    )

    start >> db_duplication_notification >> end
````

Comment: Could you update this please with your import statements? I'm hoping to know how you imported it since finding it in the Airflow docs is a little confusing for me.

Comment: @cdabel I have updated the code above. Let me know if you have any further questions. Thanks